# AmyuniPDF prints PDF document in wrong font (special characters)

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, printing

I am using **Amyuni PDF Creator .Net** to print PDF using a Windows service.

Windows service is running under Local System user account. When I tried to print using above library, it prints the PDF in wrong font. See the attachment ([Wrong font in PDF printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0notw.png)).

This issue persists with only some of the printers such as **Brother MFC-8890DW Printer**.

But for the same printer with above windows service, it prints the PDF properly when unchecked the **Enable advanced printing features** setting in above printer Properties. See the attachment ([Disable Advanced printing features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNT3n.png)).

```
using (FileStream file1 = new FileStream(pdfFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (IacDocument doc1 = new IacDocument())
    {
        doc1.Open(file1, string.Empty);
        doc1.Copies = 1;
        bool printed = doc1.Print(printer, false);
    }
}
```

But same windows service prints PDF correctly for some other printers such as HP LaserJet P1005 either **Enable advanced printing features** checked or unchecked.

Comment: Can you post a link to a publically available PDF that you created this way? At least we can then verify if there is something odd in its font handling. Failing that, I'd jot it down as a printer driver trying to be too smart, f.e., by attempting to locally cache fonts.

Comment: Can you please download the PDF file which also created by AmyuniPDF creator.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/6wwe51ro7ie7j8g/129666_OTQ.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Yeah it print using other print application. The issue here is when printing using **Windows service** under **Local System** user.

We are using Amyuni 5.0.

Thanks for looking into the issue.

Comment: When I tested with Spire.PDF library, same PDF is printed successfully using the above Windows service and the above printer correctly. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.PDF/ 

Is there something wrong with Amyuni PDF printing engine?

Answer (score 3):

Without having access to the same printer that you are using it is hard to know exactly what is happening. My best guess would be that the driver of this printer has issues dealing with process-level fonts (those that are registered using the GDI function [AddFontResourceEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183327(v=vs.85).aspx)) when "Enable advanced printing features" is checked. This is how Amyuni PDF Creator uses fonts embedded in the PDF file, which is the case for the file that you have presented.
 A possible workaround for this could be to use the [attribute "PrintAsImage" of the Document class](https://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Developer_Documentation.htm#Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_ACTIVE_X/Using_the_PDF_Creator_Control/Objects/Object_Attributes/Document_Attributes.htm).

The code would look like this:

```
//set license key This is needed only with licensed version
acPDFCreatorLib.SetLicenseKey("your company", "your activation code");

//Create a new document instance
Amyuni.PDFCreator.IacDocument doc = new Amyuni.PDFCreator.IacDocument(null);

doc.AttributeByName("PrintAsImage").Value =1;

//Open the file here (...)

//Print to default printer
pdfCreator1.Document.Print("", false);
```

Another alternative would be to save your file as xps using Amyuni PDF Creator then send the xps file to the printer:

```
// Create print server and print queue.
LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
PrintQueue defaultPrintQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
defaultPrintQueue.AddJob("my document", "c:\\temp\\mytempfile.xps", true);
```

*Disclaimer: I work for Amyuni Technologies.*

Comment: Note: GDI is not the only way to render content into a printer, there is also XPS and DirectX and the behavior of a given printer driver may change (for better or for worse) on each of them. It just happens that Amyuni PDF Creator 5.0 uses GDI for text rendering, other tools may use something else.

Comment: Thanks yms for your explanation on how fonts are embedded in Amyuni and which might cause issues under Windows service. I will tested with PrintAsImage attribute as a workaround to solve the issue. Let me know whether there are any consequences of using PrintAsImage? Please note that we are also printing with label printers and postscript printers.

Comment: Printing the pdfs as an image works but the process is very slow due to size of the file send to spooler is 15-20 times bigger and not a solution we can live with. https://www.dropbox.com/s/njh2gq9r46gd0mq/PrintAsImage-print-spooler.png?dl=0
What we have forgotten to mention is that the same printing process/code works when running it as a console application.
We also use the same pdf file and same printer.

Comment: @Sachintana I will send this to the dev team to take a look.